# Sudden picocom error: invalid baud rate

Tags: ttyusb

I am struggling accessing my beaglebone black via FTDI using picocom. It has been working without any trouble in the past few weeks. I entered following command and it would work properly.

```
sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Anyhow, I have been working with Ethernet- over- USB lately. Which wasn't a problem either. I am pretty sure I connected via picocom as well a couple of times just to check something.. So it has been working in the last few weeks. Obviously I didn't changed any settings in order to get the Ethernet working which might cause the picocom- trouble.

Anyhow. I figured you cannot do Ethernet-Over-USB and Serial FTDI at the same time. So I unplugged mUSB when trying to connect via picocom. And it came up with an error:

```
picocom v1.7
port is        : /dev/ttyUSB0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115220
parity is      : none 
databits are   : 8 
escape is      : C-a 
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
FATAL: failed to add device /dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid baud rate
```

Then I changed baud rate to `9600` just to make sure. Now, instead of the error, it says `Terminal ready`. And then it just stops and doesn't do anything anymore. I press ENTER: it still doesn't do anything.

**So my questions**
1. Why can't I do Ethernet-Over-USB and the FTDI Connection at the same time?
2. What's picocom up to with it's baud rate? How do I fix this?

**My environment**
Beaglebone Black Rev C running Debian Wheezy (3.8.13)
VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04

I am not sure whether you need These Information:

**my ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 08:00:27:89:55:d3
        inet Adresse:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
inet6-Adresse: fe80::a00:27ff:fe89:55d3/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:1386 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:982 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:962896 (962.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:95644 (95.6 KB)

lo    Link encap:Lokale Schleife 
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:395 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:395 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
          RX-Bytes:33859 (33.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:33859 (33.8 KB)

/etc/network/Interfaces

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apperently it's all been about the Virtual Box. Now that I am connected to an "actual" Ubuntu-PC I can access both at the same time.